# parse GeoJson String in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, geojson

I want to get polygon coordinates from below String.

```
{"polygon":{"type":"Feature","properties":[],"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-7302732.4720101,6527844.6333235],[-3193477.8319711,6606116.1502766],[-5111129.9973226,5001550.0527375],[-6637424.5779086,4884142.7773079],[-7772361.5737289,5158093.0866438],[-7302732.4720101,6527844.6333235]]]},"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}}}}
```

This is GeoJson string that i decode to array with below code:

```
$polygon = CJSON::decode($str);
```

when i want to get polygon i get error!

```
$var= $polygon->polygon;
```

or with below code:

```
$polygon = CJSON::decode($str,true);
$var = $polygon['polygon'];
```

although for getting coordinates:

```
foreach($polygon as $key=>$value)
$coordinates = $value['coordinates'];
or
$coordinates = $value[coordinates];
```

how can i get coordinates from geojson that i send from javascript to php for saving on postgresql with postgis?

Comment: What displays when you perform a `var_dump()` on `$polygon`?

Comment: I send polygon via $.ajax to server and have `'success'=>"function(data){console.log(data);}"`In this.I send data with this command in Yii framework `echo CJSON::encode(array('polygon'=> var_dump($polygon)));` and i see html code in console in my edited post

Comment: OK, you're new. After `$polygon = CJSON::decode($str);` add `var_dump($polygon);`. This will display ***what*** `$polygon` actually is, rather than what you think it might be.  Send the results to an empty `<div>` element on the page. This will make it easier to debug.

Comment: See [array/json analyzer](http://goo.gl/2A8Sw) to peek at the JSON rsult structure. You seem to miss the `['geometry']` step.

Comment: @Matt:Do you want to edit my code and put out put of var_dump?

Comment: Take a look at my edit. That's what I meant.

Comment: @Matt: But var_dump doesn't work into Yii controller action that $.ajax send data to it!

Comment: try, echo CJSON::encode($polygon)); the reason why you are getting the html code is the header content type is not JSON. Though, the echoed JSON string might have been within the body tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$polygon->polygon->geometry->coordinates[0]
```

or

```
$polygon['polygon']['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
```

what you have is a multidimensional array/object not sure which its being output to when decoded in your case as it appears you have a class doing it I would have just used json_decode, but anyway. Yea from the looks of it, polygon is the main object, then in it is geometry which is an object that has type and coordinates, and then coordinates has multiple objects/arrays in it.

the above samples if I typed them right will show the first set of coordinates in that object. Of course you could run it through a loop ie:

In the case that it is an object assuming your Class decodes as an object and not an array. Not exactly sure what `$polygon = CJSON::decode($str,true);` does. But if its anything like `json_decode()` then you should be all set.

This is my method of breaking down the object as you present here, its worth noting you may want to check counts, and see if the object is set first, or if the property exists in the object to prevent other means of the code breaking down the road. But what I have here is just pure example at its core, it will server its purpose though. But will not error handle which is why I say you may want to elaborate further on it doing those checks.

Anyway heres my code:

```
<?php
$str = '{"polygon":{"type":"Feature","properties":[],"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-7302732.4720101,6527844.6333235],[-3193477.8319711,6606116.1502766],[-5111129.9973226,5001550.0527375],[-6637424.5779086,4884142.7773079],[-7772361.5737289,5158093.0866438],[-7302732.4720101,6527844.6333235]]]},"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}}}}';

$polygon = json_decode($str);
echo'<pre>';print_r($polygon);echo'</pre>';

$set = 1;
foreach($polygon->polygon->geometry->coordinates[0] as $coordinates)
{
    echo 'Set '.$set.': ';$set++;
    echo $coordinates[0].','.$coordinates[1].'<br>';
}
?>
```

see it in action http://7pz.net/geojson-parse.php (scroll to the bottom)

Comment: I think I messed up my loop, may have been better to do a while loop or a for loop for the first one but, Im just trying to express concept.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.After hours i check your reply code because i first use @ Rodgers and Hammertime and i get error in my code and try to debug code and search! but after hours  i use your reply and see all things is OK.Very Thanks

Comment: I use this `ode and get error `$polygon['polygon`]['geometry']['coordinates'][0]` and `['polygon']` makes error in this code!.Why `['polygon']` doesn't work in this code!.I can't use var_dump in yii framework to get $polygon structure.How you can get structure of it.Please help me about it.Thnaks

Comment: Well its as I said before, I think I got my loop wrong every so slightly, I also did get the initial object wrong too, however I am updating my answer above

Answer (score 1):

This should give you an array of all the coordinates and print them out line by line:

```
$string = '{"polygon":{"type":"Feature","properties":[],"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-7302732.4720101,6527844.6333235],[-3193477.8319711,6606116.1502766],[-5111129.9973226,5001550.0527375],[-6637424.5779086,4884142.7773079],[-7772361.5737289,5158093.0866438],[-7302732.4720101,6527844.6333235]]]},"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}}}}';

$json = json_decode($string);

$coords_array = $json->polygon->geometry->coordinates[0];

foreach($coords_array as $c_a) {
        echo $c_a[0] . "," .$c_a[1] . "<br>"; 
    }
```

Access with:

```
$coords_array[0];
$coords_array[1];
$coords_array[2];
```

etc.

Basically you can turn the JSON string into an object and access each element with the `->` notation.

I usally use a site called http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to decode JSON and find the path I need, then simply write them out as they appear, as in as in the above - `$json->polygon->geometry->coordinates;`.

Try it out yourself on the site.

Comment: In Yii Framework Controller Class i don't know how can i use var_dump! because var_dump doesn't work in it

Comment: Dont worry about var_dump, thats only to see whats there. It's not necessary. Just use $coords_array[0]; to access each coordinate by its index.

Comment: @user1344766 try out the above code, I've amended it so it will print out all the coords line by line.

Comment: I am so confused i get this error when i want to send data with ` echo CJSON::encode(array('polygon'=> $coordinates));`I used `$coordinates = $polygon->polygon->geometry->coordinates[0];`But i get below comment error in chrome console

Comment: error:`POST http://localhost/FleetManagement/index.php/site/test 500 (PHP Error) jquery.js:8102
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jquery.js:8102
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7580
modify.mode /FleetManagement/:254
(anonymous function)`

Comment: I don't know about the framework your using, just that the above code gives the desired results. If your having difficulty with another aspect of what your trying to accomplish, i.e. an AJAX POST request, then you should ask another question, but if either of the above answers answered your original question, please mark one correct for other users' benefit.

Comment: String in my code is $polygon and after that `$polygon=CJSON::decode($str);`That i send this polygon with `echo CJSON::encode(array('polygon'=> $polygon));` and i cat get this string in my browser console that i showed it in my question as string.But when i want to send $coordinate i get above error in console.`echo CJSON::encode(array('polygon'=> $coordinate));`